# Create Hbase on Amazon EC2 and use it from python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hbase, happybase

I want to create a database Hbase on Amazon EC2 and write some test data using python Happybase. How to do it?
Please tell me links where I can read about it.
Thanks

Comment: Did you search? What did you find? Were the results not what you expected? Pls elaborate

Answer (score 0):

HappyBase author here.

The official HappyBase docs at http://happybase.readthedocs.org/ should get you started with Happybase. It features a really extensive tutorial including many code examples. I spent a lot of time on this, so I'm quite positive this should get you started.

For setting up HBase on Amazon EC2, you can start with the official Amazon docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hbase.html